# webpack separate css file with .scss and css modules

Tags: fonts, sass, webpack

I have the following @font-face declared in a fonts.scss file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: SyncSpaceStandard;
  src: url("./fonts/7cc6719bd5f0310be3150ba33418e72e.eot");
  src: url("./fonts/7cc6719bd5f0310be3150ba33418e72e.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
}
```

Relative to this location there is a 'fonts' folder with the font files

Now in a separate component.scss file (in a different folder) I am referring to this .scss in the following manner

```
@import "../../stylesheets/fonts";
```

I am using webpack for the build purpose and when I try to run the build I get an error saying that ./fonts/7cc6719bd5f0310be3150ba33418e72e.eot cannot be found.  It is trying to find the ./fonts in the folder where the file got imported into.  How do I fix this?

My webpack.config.js looks like this.

```
test: /\.scss$/,
loader:  ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', '!css-loader?modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]&sourceMap!sass?sourceMap')
```

Comment: it's 2017, why are you using a `@font-face` rule for a format that is no longer supported by anything *including* official versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer? (`eot` is only for IE8 and below, which Microsoft deprecated in January of 2016)